# Rewrite dynamic url htaccess apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, redirect, dynamic

I would need to perform a redirect by extrapolating a part of the url and then creating the new one.

Specifically, I have to redirect:
https://(part to be extracted).montecoasp.it

up:
https://(extracted part).montecosrl.it

PLEASE NOTE: The part to be extracted may not even be there.

Can anyone tell me what to write in the htaccess file? Should you use RewriteUrl, RedirectMatch or what? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+\.)?montecoasp\.it$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1montecoasp.it%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]
```

You can implement such rule in a distributed configuration file, but you should prefer to use the static http server's host configuration.

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server for this. And if you want to use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), then you need to enable those too...

In general it is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only to change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything is sorted out. That prevents nasty caching issues...

You definitely should start reading the documentation of the tools you are using. You want to learn how things work, you do not just want to blindly copy things. As typical for OpenSource software the apache documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html